# highlight input fields with the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="original" name="itens[]">
<input type="text" id="clone1" name="itens[]">
<input type="text" id="clone2" name="itens[]">
<input type="text" id="clone3" name="itens[]">
```

I want them to change color if their values repeat. Basically a loop within a loop. Like this:

```
$('input[name="itens\\[\\]"]').each(function () {
    current_value = $(this).val();
    current_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('input[name="itens\\[\\]"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == current_value && $(this).attr("id") != current_id) {
            $(this).css("background", "red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("background", "white");
        }
    });
});
```

That's producing erratic behavior that even loggin a lot to the console I don't seem able to understand. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I think the comparision is failing maybe because of types. Could really use some help.

Comment: On which event are you triggering this functionality? On blur, change, etc?

Comment: You need an event to trigger the above code to check for duplicate values

Comment: try to implement two way data binding using jquery

Comment: I was using change() event. Eventually as my little project grows I'll use more plugins (validation, jquery.my) and get more confortable with the language. For now I'll stick with the blur() event as suggest below, its simple and matches the code I've written so far. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens is that although you have the matching logic working and it does apply the background color, if it then does a comparison where it doesn't match with the next input, it removes the previously correct match. So what i've done here is broken up the if else and applied a white background to all after every blur event. Now when it finds a match it will only add color, not remove.

```
$('input[name="itens\\[\\]"]').blur(function() {
  $('input[name="itens\\[\\]"]').css("background", "white");
  $('input[name="itens\\[\\]"]').each(function() {
    current_value = $(this).val();
    current_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('input[name="itens\\[\\]"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == current_value && $(this).attr("id") != current_id) {
        $(this).css("background", "red");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/WwLZmO?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you. It worked. After a good nights sleep I found the flaw in my logic, just couldn't find an event to nest so it wouldn't overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference my code:

```
$("input[name='itens[]']").change(function(){
    var data_array = [];
    $("input[name='itens[]']").each(function () {
        if($(this).val() != "" && $.inArray($(this).val(), data_array) != -1) {
        $(this).css("background", "red");
      } else {
        $(this).css("background", "white");
      }
      if ($(this).val() != "")
          data_array.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rbkf75t/)

Comment: I tried using an array, I'm still struggling with the scope of jquery functions and syntax. I'll try the other solutions and write my own based on your great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the input values if exist or not in old value. try this below code :

```
  <input type="text" id="original" name="itens[]" value="2">
<input type="text" id="clone1" name="itens[]" value="2">
<input type="text" id="clone2" name="itens[]" value="1">
<input type="text" id="clone3" name="itens[]" value="3">

  <script>
   var inputValues =[] , repeatValues =[];

$('input[name="itens\\[\\]"]').each(function () {
    inputValues.push($(this).val());
 })
 inputValues = inputValues.sort();
  for(var count =0 ; count < inputValues.length; count++){
        if(inputValues[count + 1] == inputValues[count])
            repeatValues.push(inputValues[count])
  }
    $('input[name="itens\\[\\]"]').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(),repeatValues) != -1) {
            $(this).css("background", "red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("background", "white");
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8rbkf75t/1/